# HDMI port detected as DP

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, xrandr

recently i have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my dell 7577.
Before that, my operating system was windows 10.

But now, i have a huge error, whenever i connected my second monitor via hdmi port, it is detected as dp port, despite i don't have a dp port .
when i run the xrandr command, here is the output :

```
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-3 connected 1024x768+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94
```

the second monitor is detected as unknown display and i can't configure its resolution. It is stuck on 1024*768.

Before on my windows 10, my second monitor was detected normally.

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: have you installed the nvidia driver for your card?

Comment: yes i have installed nvidia driver
here is the output when i run nvidia-smi command:


+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0